# Django 1.11's signed_cookie session backend sets a new sessionid for every request

Tags: django

This makes the `vary_on_cookie` decorator useless because the coookie is different at every request, and also it makes the sessions never expire regardless of `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` because every request pushes the expiration forward.

I did some digging, and `process_response` in `sessions/backends/middleware.py` does `request.session.save()`, which causes the `signed_cookie` backend to create a new session key with this code:

```py
return signing.dumps(
            self._session, compress=True,
            salt='django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies',
            serializer=self.serializer,
        )
```

This code returns a different value even if called with the same argument (I guess it's built into the encryption).

Am I missing something? This doesn't sound right... any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: one of my middlewares was modifying the session in `process_request`, which caused the session object to be modified, and therefore the chain of events explained in the question happened.